# Appending to a certain element, that also doesn't have a certain class

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a table, that may have rows with a `hidden` class:

```
<table id="sortme">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="hidden" name="pr" value="1" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="hidden" name="pr" value="7" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="hidden">
            <input type="hidden" name="pr" value="4" />
        </td>
    </tr>
```

I have function that sorts the whole table according to the `input`:

```
<script>
$(function() {
    $('#sortme tr:has(input[name="pr"])').sort(function(a, b) {
        return 1 * $(a).find("input[name='pr']").val() - 1 * $(b).find("input[name='pr']").val();
    }).appendTo('#sortme');
});
</script>
```

I want to sort only the rows *without* `hidden` class.

I tried adding:

`|| tr.!(hasClass("hidden"))`

To the function this way:

```
<script>
$(function() {
    $('#sortme tr:has(input[name="pr"]) || tr.!(hasClass("hidden"))').sort(function(a, b) {
        return 1 * $(a).find("input[name='pr']").val() - 1 * $(b).find("input[name='pr']").val();
    }).appendTo('#sortme');
});
</script>
```

But that's probably not the correct syntax.

I'm not even sure if I should it over there, or at the `appendTo` part.

How should it be?

Edit:

Updated code:

I sort first by class (not-hidden), and then by numeber (lowest first):

```
  $('#sortme tr:has(input[name="pr"]):not(.hidden)').sort(function(a, b) {
    return 1 * $(a).find("input[name='pr']").val() - 1 * $(b).find("input[name='pr']").val();
  }).appendTo('#sortme');
    $('#sortme tr:has(input[name="pr"]).hidden').sort(function(a, b) {
    return 1 * $(a).find("input[name='pr']").val() - 1 * $(b).find("input[name='pr']").val();
  }).appendTo('#sortme');
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`:not`](https://api.jquery.com/not-selector/) selector to exclude some elements by using CSS selector.

```
$('#sortme tr:has(input[name="pr"]):not(.hidden)')
```

Or, [`.not()`](https://api.jquery.com/not/) can also be used

```
$('#sortme tr:has(input[name="pr"])').not('.hidden')
```

Comment: @rockyraw When used this, the hidden rows will not be considered in sort process. So, the other rows will be moved after hidden.

Comment: That explains it, So I guess I need a solution that move the regular rows *before* hidden rows, how can I do that? The thing is, that I'm also appending a `lowset value` `<div>` to the first row. So with this code, it appends it to that hidden row, just because it comes out first.

Comment: @rockyraw you can return a high number value from the `sort` callback if the current `td` has the class `hidden`. For this you need to use your first code with an additional condition.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I'm sorting by class, then by number, please see my edit. Code seems to work good when testing, what do you think?